# Countdown timer for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I would like to design a countdown timer with 55 mins time limit. And i would also like to start and stop it according to the necessity.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a scheduled timer which calls a function on completion. Here I have used done waiting method.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0f * 60.0f) target:self selector:@selector(doneWaiting:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void) doneWaiting:(NSTimer *)theTimer {  
//perform code after timer expires here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Will the app be open for the full 55 mins? You can use `[object performSelector withDelay..]` if it will. Else you might find [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) useful